# Measure the maximum value of an exponential analog signal and provide a constant supply having that same value

Tags: power-supply, comparator

I need to detect the exact time for which an exponentially decreasing analog signal is equal to the half of its maximum value. I'm using for that a digital-output comparator but I have a big problem of how to provide a constant signal equal to 0.5*Vmax on one of the comparator input. Do you have any idea that may help?
Thanks a lot.

Best regards,
Emna.

Comment: Do you trigger the process or do you have to detect the peak?

Comment: It is an exponentially decreasing signal so its maximum value is basically its first one.

Comment: sounds like you need a sample and hold circuit

Comment: Yes you are righ but I need only the first value. How can I make sure that I sampled the right value?

Comment: You obviously need to tell when the process starts in order to 'capture' the initial value and hold that. Some more context would help, eg what is generating the signal and how does it start?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to detect the exact time for which an exponentially decreasing
> analog signal is equal to the half of its maximum value.

Use a peak detector circuit to detect (and hold) the peak of the exponentially decaying signal then, use an equal resistor potential divider to produce a voltage level that is half the peak value. Finally, use a comparator with peak/2 fed to one input and the ddecaying signal to the other.

Here's a schematic of a peak detector but newer op-amps will perform a tad better: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [eevblog.com](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/blog/eevblog-490-peak-detector-circuit/?action=dlattach;attach=53071))</sub>

Capacitor "C" "holds" the peak voltage and this voltage is buffered by A2. The output of A2 can be reduced by 2 using equal value resistors forming a potential divider.

If the peak of the exponential signal is slightly different on each cycle, then when it returns back to form a peak, a positive edge detector can be used to reset the voltage stored on the capacitor before the peak is reached.

This is basically a BJT or FET that rapidly discharges the voltage. This allows for the peak of each cycle to be "recorded" as opposed to the highest peak amongst several cycles.

Comment: Andy, I'm not clear on the function of D2 in this circuit. It seems to allow A1's output to follow V1 when V1 is below the peak. Is that just to limit the output swing, or is something else going on?

Comment: @AdamHaun it limits the unwanted negative output swing of A1 saturating and therefore taking time to recover before being able to swing to a new positive peak value. If the op-amp is fast and the input is slow it isn't needed.